# How can i get a specific field using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#

I want to get All **results**

this is the API :

```
{
    "videos": {
        "results": [
            {
                "id": "5c8a4d5b0e0a267d08c32f18",
                "iso_639_1": "en",
                "iso_3166_1": "US",
                "key": "hA6hldpSTF8",
                "name": "Trailer",
                "site": "YouTube",
                "size": 1080,
                "type": "Trailer"
            },
            {
                "id": "5c8a4d740e0a26042bc441ef",
                "iso_639_1": "en",
                "iso_3166_1": "US",
                "key": "TcMBFSGVi1c",
                "name": "Trailer",
                "site": "YouTube",
                "size": 1080,
                "type": "Trailer"
            },
            {
                "id": "5c93af740e0a261053e9026d",
                "iso_639_1": "en",
                "iso_3166_1": "US",
                "key": "-iFq6IcAxBc",
                "name": "Big Game TV Spot",
                "site": "YouTube",
                "size": 1080,
                "type": "Teaser"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My code:

```
         public FormVerTrailer(string id)      
         {

            InitializeComponent();

             WebClient wc = new WebClient();

             string json = wc.DownloadString("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/"+id+"? 
             api_key={ApiKey}&append_to_response=videos");

            richTextBox1.Text += json.ToString();

            GetVideo Videos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetVideo>(json);
        }

    class GetVideo
    {

        public object[] results { get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
    }
```

Thank youuu! :D

Comment: What is wrong with what you have? Are you getting any errors? Is something else going wrong?

Comment: it say Movie.GetVideo.results.get null

but if i type:

class GetVideo
    {

        public object[] videos{ get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
    }

says:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Object[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want a class that models the object that is being returned like this.

```cs
    class JsonExample
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("iso_639_1")]
        public string ISO6391 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("iso_3166_1")]
        public string ISO31661 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("key")]
        public string Key { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("site")]
        public string Site { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("size")]
        public int Size { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        //This would be in your main class not your model but for brevity..
        public static List<JsonExample> GetListOfObjects (string json)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonExample>>(json);
        }
    }
```

And then get your array / list like this.

```cs
var data = "Get your data here";
var list = JsonExample.GetListOfObjects(data);
```

Good Luck!

Comment: And there is pretty nice feature in Visual Studio, Paste special that will auto generate class like in the answer above, directly from JSON code. Checkout this link http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2015/10/05/Creating-C-classes-from-JSON-(or-XML)-in-Visual-Studio-2015.aspx for example

Answer (score 0):

According with B. Miller

class GetVideo
    {

```
    public Videos videos { get; set; }

    public Results results { get; set; }

}
public class Videos
{
    public object[] results { get; set; }
}
class Results
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("iso_639_1")]
    public string ISO6391 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("iso_3166_1")]
    public string ISO31661 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("site")]
    public string Site { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("size")]
    public int Size { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

}
```

//Main Method

public FormVerTrailer(string id)

```
    {
        InitializeComponent();

         WebClient wc = new WebClient();

         string json = wc.DownloadString("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/"+id+"?api_key={Api-Key}&append_to_response=videos");


         GetVideo Videos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetVideo>(json);
```

int cantidad = Videos.videos.results.Length;

```
        for (int x = 0; x <= cantidad - 1; x++)

        {

            string json1 = Videos.videos.results[x].ToString();

            Results informacion = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Results>(json1);

            richTextBox1.Text += "     "+informacion.Key; //Confirm Its Ok!

        }
```

}